# Deny access for a specific windows user

Tags: vba, ms-access

Is there a way to deny access to a specific user to my ms-access db? Maybe something can be written in vba to see who the Windows user is and if it is "x" then "access denied"

Comment: `Environ("UserName")` will give you the user name. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/environ-function

Comment: Note that you can always open an Access file without executing code by pressing Shift while open the database, see https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/bypass-startup-options-when-you-open-a-database-ba66917a-68b6-4fe6-8c23-33042953a5f9. So a real secure solution is to deny access to the file on Windows level

Comment: @FunThomas that would appear to be the only solid solution - why don't you post as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Like braX and FunThomas mentioned: there is no real security in Access.

But maybe you can use something like:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    If lcase(Environ$("UserName")) = "x" Then

        MsgBox "Your access is denied", vbInformation + vbOKOnly, "Access denied"
        Application.Quit
    End If
End Sub
```

You can put this code into the load event of your start form.

Comment: And you can have a Users table and only listed users are allowed. Do a DLookup on Users to match with Environ("UserName").

Comment: Thanks! I will do what @Daniel Seeger proposes.